# Align image within button background

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm making a page with buttons that have images inside them. The logos should be in the center of the button and only shown once. I'm trying to show them within a DIV so that the images aren't accessible directly within the page.

Here's what I've got so far...

```css
.google-button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.google {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    object-size: contain;
    background: url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button class="google-button">
  <div class="google"></div>
</button>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. I just need the logo horizontally and vertically aligned within the button.

Thanks in advance :)

`UPDATE`

Here's the progress I've made.

```css
.google-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000000; 
    border-radius: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.google {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
}
```

```html
<button class="google-button" onclick="location.href='/google'">
  <div class="google"></div> 
</button>
```

Just need to get it to center in the middle now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```css
.google-button {
    width: 210px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 0;
    border:none;
}

.google {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
   <button class="google-button">
                <div class="google"></div>
              </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, just need a slight change in your css.

```css
.google-button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.google {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="google-button">
  <div class="google"></div>
</button>
```

Comment: Hey, could you check my code update please, the percentages are closer to how the button will now actually function.

Comment: You are giving `width: 100%` to your div and that's giving a problem because it will cover whole width of the parent button. Just try giving value in px like `width: 230px` and you will get the result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can also achieve more desired result by following @learningtoanimate answer. Like he has said, you can add `background-position: center;` with the width as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Built on previous answers with `background-position`

```css
.google-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000000; 
    border-radius: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.google {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
}
```

```html
<button class="google-button" onclick="location.href='/google'">
  <div class="google"></div> 
</button>
```